# Showing the determinant of two transformation matrices is the same

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{v_1 \cdots v_n \}$, $\{w_1 \cdots w_n\}$ be bases for an $F$ vector space $V$. Suppose a linear map $T:V \rightarrow V$ has matrices $A$ and $B$, respectively, relative to these
bases. Show that $\det A = \det B$.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the relation between these two matrices? Also, do you know the multiplicativity of the determinant?

Comment: I fixed the question there.. thanks again

Comment: I meant to hint at that the two matrices are conjugates of each other, hence with the same determinant. :)

Comment: Oh I got you now.. Heh thanks, dont know how I didn't see it in the 1st place. thanks a bunch

Comment: You are welcomed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ the change matrix from the basis $B$ to the basis $C$ and let $[T]_B$ the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $B$ then the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $C$ is
$$[T]_C=P^{-1}[T]_BP$$
hence using the property of the determinant we find
$$\det([T]_C)=\det(P^{-1}[T]_BP)=\det([T]_B)$$